# Как в CSS сделать выделение текста цветом?

Tags: css

Как в CSS сделать выделение текста цветом? Цвет выделения может быть в RGBA-формате, т.е. с прозрачностью.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется ввиду не выделение курсором. А изначально текста выделен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
div {
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}
div > span {
  padding: 3px 0;
  line-height: 1.45;
  background: rgba(20,172,211,.5);
  box-shadow: 10px 0 rgba(20,172,211,.5), -10px 0 rgba(20,172,211,.5);
}
```

```html
<div><span>Как в CSS сделать выделение текста цветом? Цвет выделения может быть в RGBA-формате, т.е. с прозрачностью.</span>
</div>
```